# convert pdf to html using abcpdf

Tags: abcpdf, pdf-to-html

i am looking for a method to convert a pdf document into corresponding html document using abcpdf. kindly let me know if it is feasible. FYI, My pdf document has rich text along with images.

Answer (score 1):

You can. Try this. Hopefully it'll work.

```
var doc = new WebSupergoo.ABCpdf10.Doc();
doc.Read('your Pdf byte array');
doc.Save('your HTML file path with .html extension');
doc.Clear();
doc.Dispose();
```

For documentation please have a look at the note section
http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/1-methods/save.htm

**To export as XPS, PostScript, DOCX or HTML you need to specify a file path with an appropriate extension - ".xps", ".ps", ".docx", ".htm", ".html" or ".swf". If the file extension is unrecognized then the default PDF format will be used.**

Comment: If definitely converted it to html. Any idea how to get pdf form fields in there too?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely convert HTML to PDF, but I am not sure the inverse is possible to do with abcpdf.

Perhaps you can give a try to [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) ([iTextsharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/iTextSharp-5.0.0/itextsharp-5.0.0-dll.zip/download?use_mirror=liquidtelecom))